# Real-time fs or file replication for OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd

(with locking support) How can I have a shared fs with master-master replication, so with real-time sync between them?

Comment: pretty sure OpenBSD is the wrong OS for such a need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [OpenAFS](https://openafs.org/) in the ports, but it seems only available for i386. You could ask its maintainer (Todd T. Fries todd@) if he plans to make it supported on amd64 and other platforms. If not, maybe you could do it yourself.